# C++ why is my file truncating when I restart my program?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I'm trying to use this code to read from the file and store values in a vector. This works once and displays everything correctly.

```
void SongList::LoadSongsFromFile()
{
    song temp;
    string line;
    ifstream myFile("SongListFile.txt");
    while (getline(myFile, line)) {
        myFile >> temp.title;
        myFile >> temp.artist;
        myFile >> temp.genre;
        songs.push_back(temp);
    }
}
```

I then want to append to the file, using the following:

```
void SongList::AddSong(song tmp)
{
    cout << "Enter the title, artist then genre of the song, each on a new line.\n";
    cin >> tmp.title;
    cin >> tmp.artist;
    cin >> tmp.genre;
    songs.push_back(tmp);
    ofstream myFile("SongListFile.txt");
    myFile.open("SongListFile.txt", ios::app);
    myFile << tmp.title << " " << tmp.artist << " " << tmp.genre;
    cout << tmp.title << " by " << tmp.artist << " is now a part of the song library! ";
}
```

Everything works fine, but the file will wipe and have nothing in it once I finish the program, even if I have tried to append to the file. To be clear, I need the previous contents, and new lines that I have added to be there every time I reopen the program.

Comment: myFile.flush();

Comment: @KonstantinL `ofstream` closes on destruction and flushes on closing.

Comment: Getting the entire file erased does not make much sense of course.  Consider that you might be looking at the wrong file, a chronic problem when you don't use a full path name and depend on the default working directory.

Comment: Have you looked in the file and verified it's content?

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Yes, its always empty after the second running of the program.

Answer (score 6):

`std::ofstream myFile("SongListFile.txt");` opens the file and truncates.  You should use `std::ofstream myFile("SongListFile.txt", std::ios::app);`

Otherwise you can declare the myFile object with `std::ofstream myFile;` and then open a file using it and the append option: `myFile.open("SongListFile.txt", std::ios::app);`

Comment: This works, thank you. I had a feeling it was something to do with the myFile.open function.

Comment: It is true, but strange a bit as it seems no difference between std::ios::trunc and std::ios:out (default arg).

Comment: @drewpy: Get into the habit of _reading the documentation_, starting now. Programming by guessing doesn't work.

Comment: @KonstantinL [Good documentation about the effects of `std::ios_base::openmode`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_filebuf/open) is somewhat hidden. The link has a table stating that both `out` and `out|trunc` have the same effects. The reasoning behind this is propably to be compatible with `std::fopen` modes.

Answer (score 3):

replace

```
ofstream myFile("SongListFile.txt");
myFile.open("SongListFile.txt", ios::app);
```

with

```
ofstream myFile("SongListFile.txt",ios::app);
```

or

```
ofstream myFile;
myFile.open("SongListFile.txt", ios::app);
```

what happens in your code is that the `ofstream myFile("SongListFile.txt")` opens the file with default mode `ios::out` and then the attempt to open the file with `myFile.open("SongListFile.txt", ios::app);` in the next line  fails because the file is already opened by the previous line making the `ios::app` ineffective for the file and thus every time you open the file using `ofstream`, the file gets truncated.

Answer (score 1):

Actually ofstream constructor has 3 parameters: `(const char *_Filename, ios_base::openmode _Mode = ios_base::out, int _Prot = (int)ios_base::_Openprot)`.

So the call `std::ofstream myFile("SongListFile.txt");` is equavalent to

`std::ofstream myFile("SongListFile.txt", std::ios::out);`

Remark: `std::ios::out` == `ios_base::out`.

Other possible values for the second argument are:

```
std::ios::app
std::ios::trunc
```

Deeper in CRT code this parameter is first translated according to this:

```
std::ios::out --> std::ios::out
std::ios::trunc --> std::ios::trunc | std::ios::out
std::ios::app --> std::ios::app | std::ios::out
```

And a bit more deeper it is translated into good old `fopen` modes according to this:

```
std::ios::out --> "w"
std::ios::trunc | std::ios::out --> "w"
std::ios::app | std::ios::out --> "a"
```

`fopen` modes description from MSDN:

"w" - Opens an empty file for writing. If the given file exists, its contents are destroyed.

"a" - Opens for writing at the end of the file (appending) without removing the end-of-file (EOF) marker before new data is written to the file. Creates the file if it does not exist.

TL;DR:

`std::ofstream myFile("SongListFile.txt");` - reset the file content.

`std::ofstream myFile("SongListFile.txt", std::ios::out);` - reset the file content.

`std::ofstream myFile("SongListFile.txt", std::ios::trunc);` - reset the file content.

`std::ofstream myFile("SongListFile.txt", std::ios::app);` - don't reset the file content.

First 3 variants are equivalent (for std::ofstream!).

Comment: So far, this gives best explanation how the open modes work. A [link to the documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_filebuf/open) could be added.